# Проблема с переходом на другую Activity

Tags: android, javascript, eclipse

Не получается перейти на другую Activity прямо с окна диалога. Когда по нажатию кнопки, то без проблем, а вот именно с диалога не хочет. При переходе пишет

> The constructor Intent(new
> DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){},
> Class<TwoActivity>) is undefined.

Вот код:

```
case R.id.Button:
    if (textInfo.getText().toString().equals("go")) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(OneActivity.this);
        builder1.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
            .setMessage("перейти?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Да", null);
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class); /* вот эту строчку подчеркивает красным */
                startActivity(intent1);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        };
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
        alert1.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "не надо",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: @cRabbs11, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ругается потому что в вашем анонимном классе DialogInterface.OnClickListener **this** ссылается на него, а не на Activity.

Вместо **this** в конструкторе напишите **getContext()**